# AngularJS - ng-if Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to create  a conditional table but I gave this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

My code is

```
...
<td ng-if="isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.start }}</td>
<td ng-if="!isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.end }}</td>
...
```

If I put only one of these 'td' it works. Should I use other way to do it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry, more code:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="element in status" ng-click="changeStatus(element.users,element.error)">
    ...
    <td ng-if="isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.start }}</td>
    <td ng-if="!isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.end }}</td>
</tr>
```

If this helps, `element.exec.start` and `element.exec.end` is type Date

Comment: With the code you provided it's hard to answer..

Comment: the error you posted seems to have no relation to the code you listed.  the code makes no mention of a property `mData`.

Comment: the updates to your code don't really clarify what `mData` is; either it doesn't relate to this code segment or that's not the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I found a paragraph that says:

*The "Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" error also appears when using a well-formed thead with a colspan but without a second row to obtain one th per td*

Then, I tried this:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="element in status" ng-click="changeStatus(element.users,element.error)">
    ...
    <td>
        <span ng-if="isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.start }}</span>
        <span ng-if="!isNaN(element.exec.end)">{{ element.exec.end }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
....
```

And it works!